# Appending objects to a list python

Tags: python, list, class

```
class paul(list):
    def __init__(self, file, border):
        self.list=[]
        self.file = open(file)
        instance=self.file.readlines()
        instant= instance[1:]
        for i in instant:
            self.list.append(otherclass(i,border))
```

Basically I am creating a class `paul` that I want to read every line in the file, then I only want to show every line except the first line (that's what `instant` is doing). Then I want to call the `otherclass` constructor and pass each line through it and append each object to `self.list`.

So when I say `x=paul(file)` I can then say `print x` and it will print the list with all the objects.

I have post of the statement right I think since when I say `print i` instead of `self.list.append` it prints every line based on the formatting specified in the `otherclass`. Right now when I say `print x` it is just printing an empty list.

Comment: What is the problem you're asking? That looks like a function to me but I have no idea other than that critique what to say.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to want `paul` to be a subclass of `list` *and* have a an attribute that is both named and is a `list`? Because that seems like a recipe for confusion, at best.

Answer (score 1):

`print paul(file)` outputs the empty list because you inherit `paul` from `list`, but don't append anything to it.
Try this:

```
class paul(list):

    def __init__(self, file, border):
        self.file = open(file)
        instance = self.file.readlines()
        instant = instance[1:]
        for i in instant:
            # Append to self, since you're inheriting the class
            # from list
            self.append(otherclass(i,border))
```

**Update**
To sort `paul` by third item of every element simply call

`self.sort(key=lambda x: x[2])`

inside the class. You can specify any sort predicate as `key` argument.

Comment: when I do this and then say x=paul(file) and the print x it prints a list with stuff in it now. But I am getting generic messeages for each line (i.e. __main__.otherclass instance)

Comment: @user3521527 that is probably because you haven't defined `otherclass.__repr__`

Comment: the first one worked good without the str so when I call self[2] I get the 2nd item in the list. But how do I create another function so I can sort all these items in the self list by the third item in every object (i.e. size)?

Comment: im still getting the same problem though its not printing all of the objects. when I say print x[1] it prints the proper item in the list but when I just say print x it prints 100 items (number of items in the list) but instead of printing the actual item it prints <__main__.otherclass instance at 0x02BB2210> for each item

Comment: @user3521527 @jonrsharpe is correct, you need to write something into `__repr__` method of `otherclass`. Update your question with code of `otherclass`.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner way to do it:

```
class Paul(list):
    def __init__(self, file, border):
        with open(file) as inf:
            # skip first line
            next(self.file, None)
            self.lines = [OtherClass(line, border) for line in inf]

    def __str__(self):
        return "[\n    {}\n]".format(",\n    ".join(str(oc) for oc in self.lines))
```